# Create and Track multiple types of agents under a single source

Tags: anylogic

I have a single source that I want 4 types of a product to be generated. The 4 agent types are Type1, Type2, Type3, and Type4. The condition is that I can only have one source for all the four agent types. I used the following code to successfully generate new agents in the source block:

```
randomTrue(0.2) ? new Type1() : randomTrue(0.375) ? new Type2() : randomTrue(0.6) ? new Type3() : new Type4();
```

This works, however I can't figure how to track each individual agent to compute the average time it takes each agent type to enter and leave the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use different `Source` blocks, makes your life much easier. Different agent types can flow into 1 combined flow chart downstream, no problem.

(Your code using `new Type1()` will cause a lot of trouble, if you are not careful, avoid that!)

Second, how to measure: most flexible is this:

1. add a variable of type `double` named `myTotalTime` in your 4 agent types, one in each.
2. add a variable of type `double` named `timerStart` in your 4 agent types, one in each.
3. in the `Source` blocks, you can simply use `agent.timerStart=time();`
4. where ever you want to finish the timing, you should use type-casting (assuming 4 different agent types flow through it), something like `agent instanceof Type 1 ? ((Type1)agent).myTotalTime = time()-((Type1)agent).timerStart) ...`

Step 4 is best "out-sourced" into a separate function for clarity

You *could* also think about a parent agent type for all 4 types, but this is a bit more advanced and can introduce many downsides if you don't know what you are doing :)

Comment: Appreciate the quickest response ever. The code suggestions are brilliant, unfortunately have only 1 source is a requirement. I agree that having only one source makes it difficult.

Comment: Trust me, you do not have that as a requirement. This is AnyLogic and whatever limitation you think you are having, you 99.9% likely don't :) (feel free to open another issue to solve that, and pls remember to upvote the response above if it was helpful)

Comment: Thank you, Benjamin. The expertise you have is a wealth. Wish I had at least 15 points of reputation to be able to cast an upvote, nonetheless, your answer has been checked accepted. The requirement of a single source comes from my project leader. Apparently, it was found that I could use SelectOutput5 block to split the four agents inorder to track time spent. My flowchart has a single queue and a single delay before the sink. However I am now looking for ways to combine them at the end. I want to use TimeMeasureEnd to compute averages for each. I wonder what the opposite of SelectOutput5 is!

Comment: There is no opposite. Just let the 4 flows flow into 1 block. And try to find out *why* your PM wants only 1 Source. It does not sound right, its like saying that you can only have 1 sheet in an Excel file. You arbitrarily limit yourself

Comment: Thank you very much, Benjamin! 
You're right, there was no opposite. I re-used SelectOutput5 the second time right before the Sink along with TimeMeasureEnd, and it worked! 
About my PM, I don't even want to comment, but I do concur with you about the source. Life is good otherwise! You have a great day!